# How can I get the values displayed in the Linked Report parameter dropdownbox?

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

While I am creating a linked report and want to give it default values for the parameters, I see that the default values dropdown is empty.

[Empty default values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mz9a.png)

The reports are made with an SSAS cube

I hope you guys can help me with this issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a data set for your "Default Value"
2. In parameter properties -> default values -> point to the dataset etc.
3. Done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

In SSRS I already have a dataset for the parameters, but when I want to make a linked report on the web, the values don't show up in the dropdownbox as shown in the pictures above. The funny thing is when I want to make a subscription then the I see that the dropdownbox there is filled with values.



Could this be a bug?

Comment: erm..in this case i guess its not a bug, most likely is the limitation of SSRS settings page.

Comment: I've encounter an error like this before. Check if there are null values in your dataset for the parameters. sometimes it's the null values that causes it.